# Adding additional text for html form GET method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

When using the 'get' method for form,

```
<form action="domain.com" method="get">
    Surname: <input type="text" name="ABC"><br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="DFG"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the input will be sent to a page on the server called

domain.com/?ABC=**surname**&DFG=**name**

My question: how to edit the form to make it such that the input gets sent to a page called

domain.com/?ABC=**"surname"**&DFG=**"name"**

(notice the " " around the two inputs.

Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have these in quotes?

The website in the form `GET` should be able to understand the form inputs you're sending to it without the quotes. If you *really* need to add quotes (or anything else to the form input), you can do it using jQuery.

Something like

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
   $.get('domain.com', { name: ..., surname: ...});
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

**EDIT: more info:**

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll extend what the other commenter did here. He's almost right, except instead of "%22" you need to add the quotation character ("), and it'll encode it for you. The reason it adds %25 is that its actually encoding the percent (%) character! :D

Modified from Beau Bouchard's answer:

```
function (){
      var abc = document.getElementById("ABC").value; 
      document.getElementById("ABC").value = "\"" + abc + "\"";
      var dfg = document.getElementById("DFG").value; 
      document.getElementById("DFG").value = "\"" + dfg + "\""; //changes input field value
      document.getElementById("formid").submit(); //submits the form
}
```

Comment: would really appreciate if you could elaborate how do I pull this off. Sorry i'm really new at this. Thanks.

Comment: I need these in quotes because I'm trying to link to a page where draws data from mysql database that depends on the value of variables in the URL and if the variables are not in quotes, it does not work.

Comment: See if this change is helpful, just edited my comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the quotation mark character (U+0022) which is not allowed in plain text it must be encoded as %22.

I did some javascript to add the doublequotation mark characters to your input from the user, and then it should submit the form action as before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    beforeSubmit = function(){
          var abc = document.getElementById("ABC").value; 
          document.getElementById("ABC").value = "%22" + abc + "%22";
          var dfg = document.getElementById("DFG").value; 
          document.getElementById("DFG").value = "%22" + dfg + "%22"; //changes input field value
          document.getElementById("formid").submit(); //submits the form
    }
</script>
<form action="domain.com" method="get" id="formid">
    Surname: <input type="text" name="ABC" id="ABC"><br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="DFG" id="DFG"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="beforeSubmit();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

Just tried it and the output is
domain.com?ABC=%2522surname%2522&DFG=%2522name%2522

seems like there is an extra "25".... hmmm

Comment: :D no problem, you should close this question tho